# pandas and calling function on an object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of type Object, and I want to access a property of the object into another column.

```
import pandas as pd

class foo(object):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return "bar"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [foo(), foo(), foo()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['test'])
    df['value'] = df['test'].value
```

This fails with the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'`

Is there a way to call a property or function on a class to populate a new column?

Comment: What about: `df['value'] = df['test']`?

Comment: That will just set column 'value' to the same object as test, what I want to do is get the property value of the object foo into column value: foo().value into df['value']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class foo(object):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return "bar"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [foo(), foo(), foo()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['test'])
    df['value'] = df['test'].apply(lambda x: x.value)
```

---

```
df
```

[image]